# How do I prevent Jinja links from nesting?

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app which takes any endpoint `foo/{page}` and uses the `page` variable to decide what template to render.

It looks kind of like this:

```
@api_router.get("/foo/{page}/")
def foo_router(page: str, request: Request):
    return TEMPLATES.TemplateResponse(
            f"{page}.html",
            {
                "request": request,
                'page_title':page,
                'schema':schema[page],
            }
        )
```

The templates contain buttons that are created from a schema that has button text and link destination as key/value pairs.

Something like this:

```
schema = {
    "index": {
        "Look At Our Menu":"foo/menu",
        "Find Our Store":"foo/location",
    }
}
```

And the Jinja template looks like this:

```
<div class="form_wrapper">
{% for k in buttons %}
    <a href="foo/{{buttons[k]}}/">
    <div class="button_text full_button">
    {{ k.upper() }}
    </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

My problem is if I have a link within `foo/menu/` that I want to direct to `foo/drinks`, it tries to load `foo/menu/foo/drinks`. How do I reset the path so it doesn't nest?

Comment: This seems like it is more about HTML than it is about Jinja. If you have a page `/foo/menu` and you want to link to `/foo/drinks` from a link on that page, then the relative link would be `<a href="drinks">Drinks</a>`.

Comment: right -- the problem is the endpoint that knows to read the path as a variable is `foo/{bar}`

a link to `drinks` would  go to `/drinks` not `foo/drinks`  

(actually I think the way I have it set up it would go to `foo/menu/drinks` -- same problem)  

anyways I figured something out below

Comment: You probably want to sanitize that string quite a bit before making the template module read it, I'd think?

Comment: @MatsLindh say more?

Comment: @steadynappin Instead of using a user-controlled value to directly load a template, make sure that it maps one of your expected values first to avoid the user loading random templates that you did not intend for them to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out using `request` to get the base path

```
<div class="form_wrapper">
{% for k in buttons %}
    <a href="{{ request.base_url.url + 'foo/' + buttons[k] }}/">
    <div class="button_text full_button">
    {{ k.upper() }}
    </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I'm not sure this is the best way but it does work so far!

---

Comment: Since you want the URL to the page endpoint, wouldn't `{{ url_for('foo_router', page=buttons[k]) }}` do the correct thing?

Comment: this worked and is much cleaner! thanks!